# How can I make awesome_print be the default in the heroku console?

Tags: heroku, rubygems, awesomeprint

How can I make awesome_print be the default in the heroku console?

When I type `Model.all` in the console, I would like awesome_print to display the results without having to type `ap Model.all`.

Answer (score 5):

The following gem combination seems to accomplish it in Rails 4.

```
# for the pretty
gem 'pry'
gem 'pry-rails'
gem 'pry-doc'
gem 'pry-awesome_print'
gem "awesome_print"
```

You can also remove from your `.pryrc` the following lines and it will work anyway :

```
require 'awesome_print'
AwesomePrint.pry!
```

Happy printing!

Comment: This works beautifully in rails 5.1.6 and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This is the only solution I've found that works for formatting devise models in IRB as well. Using rails 5.2.2 as well. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try installing pry, it has functionality like awesome print and more, and has instructions for installing into a rails application: http://pryrepl.org/

Comment: I was able to get pry installed, but it doesn't print with a nice layout like awesome print does. Is there a way to make it print like awesome print?

Answer (score 0):

If you have awesome_print gem you simply just use `AwesomePrint.irb!` in the console and voila.. it will display the output as how you want.